# Pydev: Go to arbitrary module source?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In Pydev, is there a convenient way to open arbitrary (external, globally installed) module?  Say, I want to see the source of `markdown.blockprocessors` module.  How can I do that without typing an import directive (`import markdown.blockparser`), using "Go To Definition" (F3) and removing the directive?  It would be nice to see the hierarchy of the whole `markdown` package in the Package Explorer, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main ways of finding something without using F3:

1. Open Resource action (Ctrl+Shift+R): allows you to find any file in your workspace (so, it's useful not only for python modules, but any file, but those need to be in your workspace).
2. The PyDev tokens browser (Ctrl+Shift+T): allows you to find any token (class/method/attributes/globals -- but currently not module name) for modules in the PYTHONPATH (either source folder or external libraries under the project properties > pydev pythonpath). You can filter things as 'myproject.*something' (the dialog that opens provides instructions on how to filter tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Add Markdown source code folder here::

```
 Project properties -> PyDev PYTHONPATH -> Source folders.
```